# Let's say it was possible. So how might one explain magic using dark matter and dark energy?

Tags: science-based, magic

This is bound to be confusing due to the varying definitions of magic, and may be considered opinion-based, but I don't understand which definition to use. 
If you guys could point me in the definition that best describes what I'm looking for, that would be nice, too. 
So, I looked at this answer ( https://www.quora.com/Is-the-Force-more-similar-to-dark-energy-dark-matter-or-neither )
And it makes sense, but how might one use that to do things like create a fireball?
If this is too much of one thing, please tell me how i might make it better.

Comment: If you have to pick between 1) explaining something using two things we don't understand or 2) not explaining it at all, I'd pick not explaining. We really don't know enough about either to answer this question.

Comment: Without Hand waving the ability to use something to Manipulate it unnaturally, (like most fairy tale magics) Dark Energy/Matter fall into the same issue Regular Energy/Matter does, we cant manipulate it through non scientific methods. However, if you want a Scientific approach but are willing to Hand wave it, using Dark energy as the explanation of why we cant use magic in real life right now (regardless of the truth of that statement), then explicitly mentioning that is a good idea, Since a solid answer would be simple, Manipulation through Willpower.

Answer (score 3):

So both are pretty weakly interacting and so are very hard for scientists to detect. We only really see their effects on a massive scale, and how they interact with things like galaxies.

So, what if your magic is a way to energize these dark forces and turn them into something that is less weakly interacting for a while.

With certain spells dark energy could be drawn from the universe and used to heat air into a plasma ball propelled at an enemy, or to power other spells.

Dark matter could be condensed and drawn out so as to create things like a temporary bridge to cross a chasm.

But you don't really need to explain how it works, just set up your rules, and set up the limitations of what it can do (more important).